# Is there an online source where you can check the standards of an Hashgacha?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I am looking for an online source where you can check the standards of any Hashgacha. (Cholov Yisroel, Glatt, Bait Yosef, Pas Yisroel, Mashgiach Temidi, vegetable checking, etc.)

Comment: great Idea especially for an app

Comment: @Chalutzhanal If you like that check out http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crc-kosher/id397991421?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

The biggest hashgachas don't have across-the-board standards on things like Cholov Yisroel or Beit Yosef meat, and the requirement for a Mashgiach Temidi is rather situational, depending on the kind of food that's being served. For example, most of the kosher restaurants in Chicago are certified by the CRC. Most or all of the restaurants owned by frum people serve Chalav Yisrael (at least the dairy ones do, but you get my point). However, there's a Dunkin Donuts and a Dairy Star (also under the CRC) that serve chalav stam.

I think you need to either rely on a list of "recommended" hashgachas (like the CRC's list or KosherQuests's list), or if you have special needs beyond the "Ashkenazi/Moshe Feinstein common base" (e.g. you require Cholov Yisroel and/or Beit Yosef) you need to find out who's certifying a particular restaurant, and call the hashgacha to find out whether that restaurant meets your standards.